# Complex Analysis Weierstrass Test

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

Hi there. I am struggling to understand the line:

$\frac{1}{2}(e^{-ny}+e^{ny}) \le e^{nr}$

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, for real $t$, we have $e^t \leqslant e^{\lvert t\rvert}$ (and $\lvert e^z\rvert \leqslant e^{\lvert z\rvert}$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}$). Hence for $-r \leqslant y \leqslant r$, we have

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{-ny} + e^{ny}\right) \leqslant \frac{1}{2}\left(e^{\lvert -ny\rvert} + e^{\lvert ny\rvert}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(e^{n\lvert y\rvert} + e^{n\lvert y\rvert}\right) = e^{n\lvert y\rvert} \leqslant e^{nr}.$$